# How to handle edge coincidence and intersection in a trapezoid map?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm currently implememting a really general trapezoid map
https://ibb.co/THsqnYz
, and have to resolve the following occasions:

- vertex coincidence
- edge coincidence (say edge from (0,0) to (0,1) and edge from (0,-1) to (0,2), or (0,0) to (0,1))
- edge intersection
- zero length edge

I had googled and read many PDFs but none of them explained this in DETAIL.

Could someone teach me how to do? (external materials are also OK)

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Do you know how to calculate two edges intersection?

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes. I have implemented a version which allows to append non-intersecting segements. I used a vector to cache 4 neighbor trapezoids of a trapezoid and do the update for each insertion. It's quite easy for non-crossing segments.

Comment: See  [segments intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Comment: @Ripi2 I know how to calculate the intersection, but what I don't know is how to update the trapezoid map when encounter intersections and coincidences.

Comment: At this point I need an image to see the issue. Can you post one?

Comment: Sure. https://ibb.co/Qpmtmgb, https://ibb.co/THsqnYz. I took the simplest intersecting occasion as the example (right column)

Comment: Moreover, since the trapezoid map is dependent on the insertion order of vertices and edges, handling insertion seems annoying since new vertices will be introduced.

Comment: This [link to pdf](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2021/cmsc754/Lects/lect08-trap-map.pdf) and this [link to pdf](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2020/cmsc754/Lects/lect09-pt-loc.pdf) will give enough info & samples

Comment: Notice that if you allow intersecting edges then the whole idea of space partition gives away. what you can do is **1)** Find all intersections, and insert new vertices. **2)** Overlapped edges with no other segments in between can be treated by getting the 4 vertices, unless they are repeated. **3)** Segments in between require inserting vertices. If you need the original data you may keep a track of the edges modified or inserted.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thank you for the helpful comments! Furtherly, I have some detailed questions: **1)** If I find the intersections first, I need to implement a segment set intersection algorithm, so I wonder is there any possible method to allow finding intersections while adding segments (and maintain the trapezoid map at the same time). **2)** what should I do if  the overlapped edges are repeated? **3)** As for "Segments in between require inserting vertices", could you please make it clearer on how to do in detail? I'm not sure about this.

Comment: When you add a segment you must check for intersections with all previous segments. This is slow, but can be some optimized. If it intersects you must split both segments and add the intersection point, and change the map/tree accordingly. Overlapped edges are like intersections, split segments and add the endpoint inner to the oher segment, perhaps two insertions. Repeated edges must be discarded (but you can store its original data, so as to say "this point lies at right of segments XX and YY)

Comment: Perhaps you want to first check all intersections (search algorithms like "Sweep Line") and later begin with the map.